# Python Django: Handling URL with Google App Engine - Post then Get

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I have something like this set up:

```
class CategoryPage (webapp.RequestHandler):
def get(self):
    ** DO SOMETHING HERE **
def post(self):
    ** DO SOMETHING HERE **
    ** RENDER THE SAME AS get(self)
```

The question is, after I process the posted data, how would I be able to display the same information as the get(self) function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A redirect, as others suggest, does have some advantage, but it's something of a "heavy" approach.  As an alternative, consider refactoring the rendering part into a separate auxiliary method `def _Render(self):` and just ending both the `get` and `post` methods with a call to `self.Render()`.

Comment: Can you please give a small example on how to implementation it.

Answer (score 1):

Call self.redirect(url) to redirect the user back to the same page over GET. That way, they won't accidentally re-submit the form if they hit refresh.

Answer (score 0):

```
create_object(request, form_class=FormClass,
        post_save_redirect=reverse('-get-url-handler-',
                                   kwargs=dict(key='%(key)s')))
```

I use the above django shortcut from generic views where you can specify post save redirect , get in your case .
There are few more examples in this snippet .
Btw, I assumed that you are using django ( helper or patch) with app engine , based on the title of the question.
If you are using app engine patch , check out the views.py in "myapp" app sample add_person handler does what you are looking for.

Comment: I do have the django help with app engine. Would it be possible if you explain the above code a bit ? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

That's generally not a good idea as it'll cause confusion.  You should really do whatever it is you want to do and then redirect them to the get method.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, your code isn't Django, but webapp (Google's mini-"framework"). Please read the Django documentation: http://docs.djangoproject.com/

Django's generic views are only available with app-engine-patch. The helper doesn't support them. You could take a look at the app-engine-patch sample project to learn more about Django on App Engine: http://code.google.com/p/app-engine-patch/